# Get the right jquery datatable object on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to remove a row from a datatable table with an on click event. I got this based on the documentation and my code works. 
However I don't want to hard code the variable name for my datatable object in the remove function as there might be multiple or differently called datatables. How can I determine the correct object where the row should be removed?

Updated code in codepen https://codepen.io/bintux/pen/QWLKxQG based on @David Hedlund's answer.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('.deleterow').on('click', function () {
    //I want to avoid this hard coded name for the datatable object but instead get the right object when the user clicks in the table    

    table
        .row($(this).parents('tr'))
        .remove()
        .draw();

});
```

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$('.deleterow').on('click', function() {
  table
    .row($(this)
      .parents('tr'))
    .remove()
    .draw();
  //console.log(row);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Remove</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Remove</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="deleterow">X</span></td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="deleterow">X</span></td>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span class="deleterow">X</span></td>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.deleterow` will always be a child of the table of interest.

Inside your click listener, you could access it like so:

```
var table = $(this).closest('table').DataTable();
```